# How to pass parameters and based on them create a condition in markup?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-partial

I'm a newbie. 
How to pass parameters and based on them create a condition in markup?
I have such a component

```
{% component 'demoTodo' %}
```

but I want to use it in two variations, if mobile = true, then another markup, if false another
`{% component 'demoTodo' mobile=true %}` or `{% component 'demoTodo' mobile=false %}`

```
{% if mobile == true %}
  ...
{% else %
...
{% endif %}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `component property` and retrieve it in `onRender` method and again need to pass it to markup.

You can follow this process to get `mobile` variable to your `markup`.

> Your page markup where you include `component` with property `mobile`

```
{% component 'demoTodo' mobile=true|false %}
```

> Inside your `demoTodo` component `php` code

```php
function onRender() {
   $this->page['mobile'] = $this->property('mobile');
}
```

> in your component's `default.htm` markup nor `mobile` variable will be available

```
{% if mobile == true %}
  ...
{% else %
  ...
{% endif %}
```

if any doubt please comment.